# How to properly configure one service with multiple configurations?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

Please help me how to correctly configure one service(1 class) with several configurations and, depending on the condition, call the service with different configuration. The     configurations for the service are stored in the appsettings.json file

*MailConfig*:

```
public class MailConfiguration
    {
        public string? DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string? From { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? Password { get; set; }
        public string? Host { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public bool UseSSL { get; set; }
        public bool UseStartTls { get; set; }
    }
```

*MailService:*

```
public class MailService : IMailService
    {
        private readonly MailConfiguration _settings;

        public MailService(IOptions<MailConfiguration> settings)
        {
            _settings = settings.Value;
        }

        public async Task<bool> SendAsync(MailData mailData, CancellationToken ct = default)
        {
           //Implementation
        }
}
```

*IMailService*:

```
public interface IMailService 
{              
Task<bool> SendAsync(MailData mailData, CancellationToken ct);
}
```

*Configure Service:*

```
builder.Services.Configure<MailConfiguration>builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MailConfiguration)));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMailService, MailService>();
```

*Just an example of the configuration I want to implement:*

```
"MailConfiguration": [
    {
      "DisplayName": "Client1",
      "From": "testclient1@gmail.com",
      "Password": "qwerty123",
      "Host": "smtp.gmail.com",
      "Port": 465,
      "UserName": "testclient1@gmail.com",
      "UseSSL": true,
      "UseStartTls": true
    },
    {
      "DisplayName": "Client2",
      "From": "testclient2@gmail.com",
      "Password": "qwerty123",
      "Host": "smtp.gmail.com",
      "Port": 465,
      "UserName": "testclient2@gmail.com",
      "UseSSL": true,
      "UseStartTls": true
    }
  ]
```

How would this be done better in terms of best practices?

**I would be very grateful, I hope someone will answer my question**

I had several thoughts, but they all boil down to antipattern implementations
I thought about "factory" and "decorator", but both of my implementations use the "Dictator" anti-pattern, in which the service instance is explicitly created using the new() keyword. I feel like I'm doing something wrong

Comment: So you want a different instance implimenting `IMailService` for each client configuration? seems like a pretty bad design from where I stand.

Comment: Hello, Zohar Peled. I will try to explain in more detail so that my idea is clearer.

I created a IdentityServer. This server is used for authentication by 2 different applications. Therefore, I want to send emails like ForgotPassword, ConfirmEmail from different email addresses, depending on the application from which the user logged into IdentityServer. Therefore, I would like to configure one service with different configurations

Comment: So... each application has its own client in the configuration file? What will happen if you have to support 10 applications? 100? this doesn't seem to scale very well....

Comment: I agree with you. You are probably referring to microservice architecture. That the mail service should be in a separate application and work through a message broker.
It will probably be bad idea to create 2 different services MailService1:IMailService and MailService2:IMailService the same, but with a different configuration and use the "Factory".
Perhaps you can offer your implementation option?

Comment: That really depends on the level of abstraction you want to provide. I would suggest having the applications using the service provide the email details, either as a part of the `MailData` or by registering to the service, providing the details and getting a unique key (a Simple GUID would be a good option) and then use that key whenever sending the data. The technical details such as port and UseSSL you can leave in the configuration of the service, to create a dictionary or list of supported email providers, if you want to abstract that information away from the client applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not the best practice, but as a temporary solution it is fine. I hate questions that remain unanswered, so I will add my temporary solution, even if not the best

Service

```
public interface IMailService
    {
        Task<bool> SendAsync(SenderSettings sender, MailData mailData, CancellationToken ct);
    }



public class MailService : IMailService
{
    private readonly EmailSettings _settings;

    public MailService(IOptions<EmailSettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings.Value;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SendAsync(SenderSettings sender, MailData mailData, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        try
        {
            // Initialize a new instance of the MimeKit.MimeMessage class
            var mail = new MimeMessage();

            #region Sender / Receiver
            // Sender
            mail.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(sender.DisplayName, mailData.From ?? sender.From));
            mail.Sender = new MailboxAddress(mailData.DisplayName ?? sender.DisplayName, mailData.From ?? sender.From);

            // Receiver
            foreach (string mailAddress in mailData.To)
                mail.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(mailAddress));

            // Set Reply to if specified in mail data
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailData.ReplyTo))
                mail.ReplyTo.Add(new MailboxAddress(mailData.ReplyToName, mailData.ReplyTo));

            // BCC
            // Check if a BCC was supplied in the request
            if (mailData.Bcc != null)
            {
                // Get only addresses where value is not null or with whitespace. x = value of address
                foreach (string mailAddress in mailData.Bcc.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
                    mail.Bcc.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(mailAddress.Trim()));
            }

            // CC
            // Check if a CC address was supplied in the request
            if (mailData.Cc != null)
            {
                foreach (string mailAddress in mailData.Cc.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
                    mail.Cc.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(mailAddress.Trim()));
            }
            #endregion

            #region Content

            // Add Content to Mime Message
            var body = new BodyBuilder();
            mail.Subject = mailData.Subject;
            body.HtmlBody = mailData.Body;
            mail.Body = body.ToMessageBody();

            #endregion

            #region Send Mail

            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();

            if (_settings.UseSSL)
            {
                await smtp.ConnectAsync(_settings.Host, _settings.Port, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect, ct);
            }
            else if (_settings.UseStartTls)
            {
                await smtp.ConnectAsync(_settings.Host, _settings.Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls, ct);
            }
            await smtp.AuthenticateAsync(sender.UserName, sender.Password, ct);
            var response = await smtp.SendAsync(mail, ct);
            await smtp.DisconnectAsync(true, ct);

            #endregion

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var x = ex;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Sender configuration model

```
public class SenderSettings
    {
        public List<string> ClientIds { get; set; } //mobileclient, web client and etc
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

Email configuration model

```
public class EmailSettings
    {
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public bool UseSSL { get; set; }
        public bool UseStartTls { get; set; }
    }
```

appsettings.json

```
"EmailSettings": {
    "Host": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "Port": 465,
    "UseSSL": true,
    "UseStartTls": false,
    "SenderSettings": [
      {
        "ClientIds": [ "web-client", "mobile-client" ],
        "DisplayName": "Test1",
        "From": "test1@gmail.com",
        "Password": "qwerty1",
        "UserName": "test1@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "ClientIds": [ "web-client2", "mobile-client2" ],
        "DisplayName": "Test2",
        "From": "test2@gmail.com",
        "Password": "qwerty2",
        "UserName": "test2@gmail.com"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Add DI(configure service) Startup.cs or Program.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<List<SenderSettings>>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(EmailSettings)).GetSection(nameof(SenderSettings)));
builder.Services.Configure<EmailSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(EmailSettings)));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMailService, MailService>();
```

Example:Create MailData

```
        List<string> to = new List<string>() { 
        "test-recipient1@gmail.com", "test-recipient2@gmail.com"
        };        
        string subject = "Welcome to our app";
        string body = "Dear user....";

        MailData mailData = new MailData(
            to: to,             
            subject: subject,
            body: body);
```

In the application, you receive a current clientId and using his settings send an email on his behalf. In this context, under the name of the clientId, I mean the client from the appsettings.json file. My clients: "web-client", "mobile-client", "web-client2", "mobile-client2".

```
var sender = _senderSettings.First(n => n.ClientIds.Contains(clientId));
bool result = await _mailService.SendAsync(_senderSettings.First(), mailData, new CancellationToken());
```

@ZoharPeled I want to thank you again, you are the only one who tried to help me